# Purpose of Hibernate Session locking using interceptor in method calling session.save/update

Tags: java, hibernate

Please help me in understanding the usage of session lock.

Hibernate session is re-associated to the detached object using AOP interceptor which will perform the below logic

```
session.buildLockRequest(LockOptions.NONE).lock(object);
```

Is there is any advantage of using this interceptor in method which call the session.save/update?

Will the optimistic locking ignored when the session lock is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on what object is. This will basicly tell the session that object is a *unmodified persistent entity* which should now be associated to the session the same way as objects loaded through the session.